# How do I calculate DC motor speed for a given load?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque

Suppose I have a robot of a given mass, and I'm choosing between 2 different wheels and 2 different motors to put on it. For each wheel I have the diameter, and for each motor I know the stall torque and free speed. How would I figure out which motor and wheel combination will make the robot move the fastest?

My calculations show to use the big motor with the big wheels, but the small motor with the small wheels goes faster than the big motor with the small wheels. I am not sure my calculations are correct, I need to know the correct way to work this problem.

Comment: Hi cyberike! While I am no expert on DC motors your problem should not be too hard to solve. Could you clarify a bit what you mean by "move the fastest"? Are you asking for maximum acceleration, top speed or fastest travel time for a given distance (incl. breaking at the end)? Also if you have done calculations already, why not include them here. From the DC motor perspective there are different torque/speed/power relations possible, so for a realistic estimate you need a diagram like this (http://amci.com/stepper-motor-control/images/integrated-stepper-smd23-240-curve.gif) for your motor.

Comment: Following is the information Alexander asked for. unfortunately, I don't know how to do equations the way ja72 has in his reply, so I have to describe. I am looking for the top speed (after acceleration) of the robot itself.

Comment: I started with the formula from the MIT website (given below by pygmalian):

ω = ω0 (1 - τ/τ_0  ) which comes basically from the motor characteristic curve and shows that a shunt wound DC motor speed decreases with an increased load on the motor.

I used the same formula to calculate torque load on the motor that ja72 gives in another comment below, τ = rF (F is the weight of the robot, a constant, and r is the radius of the wheel), so the torque required from the motor increases as wheel radius increases. This seems logical, but this is the part I was trying to confirm.

Comment: Basically, it says that the motor has to work harder for each rotation. As long as I am using the formulas correctly, I am fine. However, if I am not using them correctly I need to know it before I present it to my class.

Since the load on the motor goes up with larger wheels, the motor slows down for the larger wheels according to the first formula. My students would have to plug the numbers into each formula to see if the motor slows down more (or less) than the increased movement you get per rotation from the larger wheels. The point is, big wheels on a robot are not always better.

Comment: If you neglect the acceleration and are interested in top speed only the answer is easy: $\text{speed} = 2\pi \cdot \text{radius} \cdot \text{revolutions}/\text{second}$, so big wheels with motor with high rpm will always be faster. This totally neglects inertia and torque though and is not a very educative treatment of the problem.

Comment: My point is to include the effects due to torque. A higher load on the motor slows the motor down. My original question was: how do larger wheels - everything else stays constant - increase the load on the DC motors? I "assume" the increased load is linear with the radius of the wheel.

Comment: Your problem is still not defined enough, for "top speed" torque does not matter at all. Your assumption about linear load with radius is not correct. So it is unphysical to calculate something with assumptions that are wrong to begin with.

Comment: A DC motor always slows down when the load applied to it increases. The load (weight) in a robot is applied to a DC motor through the wheels. Wheel size affects the load on a motor as if the wheel were a lever arm. If the effect is not linear, what is it? You must take into account that the speed of a motor is not constant, nor is the torque a motor produces. Load determines the torque a motor produces, and it will produce a higher torque at a lower speed. I am asking for help, not trying to tell you anything. How do you work this problem?

Comment: Cyberike: Maybe we should move this to chat. I am trying to help you and I think I know how you want to approach the problem. The main issue is that anything concerning the mass of the robot, wheels or torque does not influence the top speed. It will greatly influence the time needed to accelerate and therefore the total time for a given distance. After a long time you will always have a balance of forces and in a model without friction your DC motor operates at maximum rpm with zero torque.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3220/discussion-between-alexander-and-cyberike)

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the size of the wheels, and ignoring air resistance, if the motor is making $P = T(\omega)\;\omega$ power then the acceleration is

$$ a= \frac{T(\omega)\; \omega}{m v} $$

The motor speed is $\omega = \frac{v}{r} $ where $r$ is the wheel radius. If the torque at $\omega=0$ is $T_0$ and the motor speed at $T=0$ is $\omega_0$ then the torque function is

$$ T(\omega) = T_0 \left( 1- \frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right) $$

The time it takes to reach a certain speed $v$ is

$$ t = \int_0^v \frac{1}{a}\;{\rm d}v $$ 
$$ t = \int_0^v \frac  { m v } { T_0 \left( 1- \frac{v}{\omega_0\,r}\right) \frac{v}{r} } \; {\rm d} v $$
$$ t = \frac{m \omega_0 r^2}{T_0} \ln\left(\frac{\omega_0 r}{\omega_0 r - u} \right) $$

or

$$ v(t) = v_0 \left( 1 - \boldsymbol{e}^{-\frac{T_0}{r} \frac{t}{m v_0} } \right) $$ where $v_0 = \omega_0\,r$ is the theoretical top speed.

So to get to $99$% of top speed you need

$$ t_{99} = \frac{m\, r^2\, \omega_0} {T_0}\; 2\ln(10) $$

From here you plug in your values and see which one has the highest top speed and which one has the highest acceleration (least time).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have one more question: How do you convert weight load to torque load on the motor given that motor force is applied at radius r of the wheel? By the way, I am working from a speed vs. torque relationship similar to http://www.me.mtu.edu/~wjendres/ProductRealization1Course/DC_Motor_Calculations.pdf

Comment: The tractive force is $F=T/r$ and the linear speed is $v=\omega \, r$.

Comment: @Cyberike I definitely agree with ja72 about independence of tractive force on mass and on the fact that you need to have some kind of motor characteristics (torque vs frequency)...

Comment: @Cyberlike See also, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23020/.  Maybe you should invite Alexander to provide his insight.

Comment: @Cyberike I took liberty to invite Alexander myself.

Comment: @ja72 Your derivation is intuitively excellent.  I just don't get one thing.  I have a heavy duty DC motor and his most important characteristics are working frequency and torque at working frequency and not stall torque ($T_0$).  This contradicts your torque vs. frequency characteristics.

Comment: Here is the site on DC motor characteristics: http://lancet.mit.edu/motors/motors3.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate the work you are doing to help a stranger. This MIT site is one of the ones I have been using, the formula I used in one of the comments below is the MIT formula (4). I will definitely ask Alexander for his insight.

Answer (score 0):

The solution $might$ be dependent on the context.  Mechanical engineers would do power calculation first.  What is prevalent about these motors, torque or power or frequency?

Concerning torque $\tau = r F$, so $F = \tau/r$ and motor with larger torque and smaller wheels give larger force (push), while the car is accelerating.

Concerning power $P = F v = M \omega$ the size of wheels is irrelevant (well at least for the time car is accelerating) and motor with larger product of torque and frequency will do the best, while accelerating.

Concerning frequency $v = \omega r$, larger frequency and bigger wheels give larger speed.

I thing the first two can give you which shall **accelerate** faster, while the last one which robot shall have higher final **speed**.

Let's suppose that power cannot be calculated using free speed.  Then you have four possible robots with four possible accelerations and four possible top speeds. **Then results depends on the track length!**

Answer (score 0):

This look suspiciously like a homework question, so we're allowed to discuss concepts but not just answer your question (or your professor won't be too pleased :-).

Your question doesn't say what the rolling resistance is e.g. what is the wind resistance the robot feels as it starts moving? If there is no rolling resistance both motors will simply accelerate until they reach their free speed, and in that case you want the highest free speed with the largest wheels.

If there is rolling resistance then the motor will accelerate until the rolling resitance is the same as the force generated at the wheels i.e. the torque times the wheel radius, so it's the torque rather than the free speed that matters.

Comment: This is not a homework question, this is for a classroom tutorial on robotics that I am making (as a teacher). I want to make sure I am using the right formulas. By the way, I am not trying to make it too complicated, so moment of inertia answers are out.

Comment: I guess that there is no rolling and wind resistance, that would make the task quite difficult, but torque might be important to get the robot that accelerates faster.

Comment: @Cyberike This thingy has kinematic part too.  Let's say one robot has larger acceleration and smaller top velocity, and the other the opposite.  Then results depends on the competition **track length**!

Comment: Oh you're teacher.  Luckily, I work at technical universities and bump into civil and mechanical engineers (with PhDs) every day.  If I'd had your problem, I would simply ask the most competent of them.